# Recursively process files in a directory in unix

Tags: shell, unix, recursion, scripting, xargs

I have made a script (convert.sh) to convert json files in pretty print format. For example,

```
convert.sh source.json
```

It will replace the source.json file, overwrite itself with pretty print format.

Content of convert.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
INFILE=$1
python -m json.tool $INFILE > $INFILE.tmp
mv $INFILE.tmp $INFILE
```

It works very well for one file. However, I would like to process all files under a directory. e.g.

```
dir1\file1.json
dir1\file2.json
dir1\subdir\abc.json
dir1\subdir2\def.json
...
```

Any single line command to do this? I tried

```
find dir1 | grep .json | xargs convert.sh
```

but no success. Please kindly help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: remove everything after the first `|`. Does `find dir1` output your complete list of files? Some versions won't do that. You might need `fin dir1 -print` (or similar). Good luck.

Comment: The find output is correct. Seem the problem is not related to it.

Comment: I tried to comment out the last line of my script "mv $INFILE.tmp $INFILE" to see any tmp files created. 
After running the whole xargs command, I found only one tmp file created. It seem it can only process one file in the find list (that is the first line of the find output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` to (1) search for file matching some pattern (2) launch your script on each found file:

```
find dir1 -name "*.json" -exec convert.sh {} \;
```

Comment: `;` is the sequential operator for shells, but find need one to delimit the end of the subcommand, so you need to tell the shell not to interpret it for itself, thus to be prefixed with \.